# Spring @PropertySource finding properties file in PREVIOUS folder

Tags: java, spring, properties, path

Currently my Spring application gets its property file like this :

```
@PropertySource("file:${MDHIS_HOME}/config.properties")
```

The solution I am developing is actually 2 projects which share the same config file.  For that reason, I cannot just point it to the classpath since the config file is actually in the folder prior to the actual project folder.  I've been using an environment variable until now and everything works great but as we work on deploying the application on different systems I'm starting to find this very annoying.  Is there a way to use classpath: in there but tell it to check the previous folder?  I would set both projects like this and never need an environment variable anymore.

***EDIT***

As requested, my project structure is quite simple.  I have a main folder that contains both project folders.  Since both projects share the same config file, I store it in the "parent" folder of each project which is the main folder in question.  Basically, the config file is a folder above each project folder.  I want each project to access this file DYNAMICALLY without the need for an environment variable.  Since my apps are intended to be deployed anywhere the user wants (while still retaining the above structure) I need this file to be accessed with a relative path somehow.

Cheers

Comment: You have provide absolute path rather than relative path. You can use classpath way.

Comment: Well it is absolute in the sense that it uses an environment variable which contains the rest of the full path yes.  I am looking for a way to point to a folder PRIOR to the classpath AKA not in the project folder but the folder containing it since this folder contains both projects and the config file which both projects use.

Comment: You know how you can put .. in a path and it goes to the previous folder?  Can this be done with the PropertySource annotation somehow?

Comment: Coud you share your projects folder structure?

Comment: added clarifications